# Que tipo de ciclo crear para validar un archivo de texto con etiquetas xml.C++

Tags: c++

Buenas noches este ejercicio me tiene bastante preocupado, se supone que debo hacer un programa en c++ donde verifique de un archivo de texto que tiene una estructura de etiquetas xml.

Se quiere desarrollar un programa en C++ que permita validar en un archivo de texto con contenido XML si por cada etiqueta que se abre, se tiene su correspondiente etiqueta de cierre. Por ejemplo, la siguiente representación en XML no es válida:

```
<menu_almuerzo>

             < comida>

                     < nombre>Waffles

                     < precio>Bs 2000.00< /nombre>< /precio>

                     < descripcion>Waffles baratos de McDonalds< /descripcion>

                     < calorias>650< /calorias>

             < /comida>

             < comida>

                < nombre >Hamburguesa< /nombre>

                < precio> Bs 5000.00< /precio>

                < descripcion>La hamburguesa mas común de McDonalds< /descripcion>

                < calorias > 1500

                < / comida >

< / menu_almuerzo >
```

La etiqueta < /nombre> no está ubicada en donde debería estar y adicionalmente falta la etiqueta de cierre de < calorías>.

El programa debe leer el archivo en XML denominado entrada.xml y debe visualizar por consola si el archivo es válido o no.

¿Cómo debo hacer los ciclo de verificación? voy guardando las etiquetas en una `struct`?

Comment: Usa [pugixml](https://pugixml.org/).

Comment: El problema es que no puedo usar una libreria de manejo de archivos xml :( tengo que hacerlo paso a paso, se supone que primero deberia verificar la etiqueta raiz y de ahi partir hacia las demas pero nose como hacer ese ciclo sin que finalize el archivo